# Bind multiple events to the same trigger

Tags: atrius-solution-builder

In a dataflow, I have two different events that I want to cause the same action to be triggered.

This is inside of a dataflow symbol. One is a trigger symbol property, the other is the `onLoop` event of a Stopwatch block. I'm trying to bind these both to the `invoke` trigger on a State block.

If I drag one, then the other to the `invoke` trigger, it only keeps the most recent binding.

I tried binding the symbol property to the `onLoop` event on the Stopwatch, and then binding that to the `invoke` action on the State block. And this works when I invoke the trigger from the symbol properties. But when in use, this does not seem to work, and only the Stopwatch's `onLoop` is actually invoking the trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind your trigger property and your `onLoop` property to an "Event Hub" block.  Then bind your Event Hub to the `invoke` property of your action block. The Event Hub will effectively do an "or" for you.